# How to make a Dojo dijit form programmatically

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

Im new to Dojo and im trying to make some ui, but only using the programmatic way.

I would like if someone could show me some example of how to make a form programmarically using Dojo dijit.form.Form. I've been looking for some example but all i can find is the declarative way of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more object oriented solution:

```
define( [
"dojo/_base/declare", 
"dijit/form/Form",
"dijit/form/Textarea",
"dijit/form/Button"
],

function(declare, Form, TextArea, Button) {
    return declare( "mypackage.MyForm", Form, {
        textarea: new TextArea({}),

        submitButton: new Button({
            type: "submit",
            label: "ready!"
        }),

        constructor: function(args) {
            declare.safeMixin(this, args);
        },

        onSubmit: function() { 
            alert(this.textarea.get('value')); 
        },

        postCreate: function() {
            this.domNode.appendChild( this.textarea.domNode );
            this.domNode.appendChild( this.submitButton.domNode );
        }
    });
}
);
```

Just drop a `new mypackage.MyForm({})` at any place you might expect a widget.

Comment: Quick comment: shouldn't you have submitButton and textarea as variables defined in the constructor instead? They are objects, and they will end up in the prototype this way... which I think is not recommended!

Comment: Could you include a fiddle? what does safeMixin do? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Its pretty straight forward.  You just create all the pieces of the the form, and then append all the pieces to their respective parent.  To create the form objects, like any dijit object, you pass the constructor a **param** object, and a **domNode** to place it at, like so:

```
var resetbtn = new dijit.form.Button({
    type: 'reset',
    label: 'Reset'
}, dojo.doc.createElement('button'));
```

The full example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jumpnett/BquNz/).  To find out what properties can be added to the params object, see the [API Docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.6/dijit/form/Form).  Any of the properties can be added to the param list.